# Not able to save file deployed on jetty server

Tags: webstorm

I have deployed my webapplication on a jetty server, and I am trying to edit those deployed files using WebStorm 8.0.4. But I am unable to save the edited files and getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try turning the 'safe write' feature (Settings/General, 'Use safe writes') off - does it help? It creates a temporary copy of a file: creates a separate temp file, deletes the original and then renames. With this option the original file permissions may be lost, this causes problems, especially when working on remote drives.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

1. Open `C:\Users\YourUserName\.m2\repository` (If you use maven)
2. Find `org` folder and Navigate `org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\yourJettyVersion`
3. There will be a .jar file.
4. Open it with winrar or some program like winrar.
5. Navigate `org\eclipse\jetty\webapp`
6. Find `webdefault.xml` and Open it with any text editor.
7. Search `useFileMappedBuffer` parameter in file
8. You will see a param value.
9. Change it to false.
10. Save and Exit.

I'm sorry for any English mistakes.